# Ignore a file url from android webview caching

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I want to Android webview cache my website. But I don't want to cache a js file that maybe update every 5 minutes. Is it possible to ignore this file from android webview caching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, one can only set caching completely to false:

```
mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);
mWebView.clearCache(true);
```

You could ignore caching to that specific js file by using a timestamp as a request parameter when loading that file.

For example, you could include your js file like this:

```
<script src="js/my_script.js?ver=1626534617"></script>
```

(where 1626534617 is the current Unix timestamp)

Using a parameter like that, will result in always requesting for the file from the server, hence bypassing the webview cache.